# catastrophic failure trying to select from linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I have created a linked oledb/odbc connection to Pervasive SQL from SQL SERVER 2012:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [KSLAP208]    Script Date: 2/8/2013 10:38:55 AM ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'KSLAP208', @srvproduct=N'Pervasive ODBC Interface', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'C003', @location=N'localhost'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'KSLAP208',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Test Connection is succesful.

However, when I try to select from a database:

```
select * from [KSLAP208].[C003]..PA_Profile_BASE_1119
```

I immdiately get just the field names returned and then immediately after that I get this error:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "KSLAP208" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "KSLAP208".
```

What am I doing wrong? Why Can I not select? I am able to see all the databases and tables on the linnked server.

**if I select a small amount of data select field1,field2 it works without problems.**

Comment: Shouldn't this question belong on dba.stack?

Comment: Is your sql server 32 bit or 64 bit?  What bit is the pervasive server?

Comment: @bluefeet the pervasive is 64 bit and the sql server 2012 is 64 whereas another sql server 2005 that had no problems adding pervasive as linked server is 32 bit\

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I remember this being an issue  when I created a postgresql linked server. I think you may need to recreate the linked server with this set to false (or just change it in the linked server properties->server options):

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'KSLAP208', 
    @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false'
```

Additionally, try using [`OPENQUERY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) to run this against the link

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(KSLAP208,'SELECT * FROM PA_Profile_BASE_1119');
```

Comment: You may also need to ensure that you're using the correct drivers, and this assumes that you've linked to the correct database.

Comment: so it looks like select individual fields works but i cannot select *

Comment: can you select all columns (essentially select * without the *)? what is the error that is given?

Comment: no i cannot i get this error when i select more than around 15 fields: The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure

Comment: sql server error logs showing: SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 55 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is 
terminating this process.  *   Access Violation occurred reading address 0000000009400090                                                   
* Input Buffer 128 bytes -

Comment: That's starting to sound a lot like a driver issue.

Comment: In general if you get an access violation I would expect a bug in some binary module somewhere, and drivers would be a major suspect.

Comment: @ChrisTravers I'm almost certainly in agreement that there's something going on at the driver level given the thread [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34436/selecting-more-fields-causes-catastrophic-failure).

Answer (score 2):

When I access remote tables, I need to have complete 4-part naming.  Try this:

```
select * from [KSLAP208].[C003].dbo.PA_Profile_BASE_1119
```

I've never investigated why.  I've just gotten in the habit of including all parts.

You can get the list of columns using:

```
select column_name
from [KSLAP208].[C003].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'PA_Profile_BASE_1119'
```

(and schema_name = whatever if you need that).

Comment: Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "KSLAP208". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.

Comment: so it looks like select individual fields works but i cannot select *

Comment: That is really interesting.  I can definitely `select *`, but need the schema.  Different security settings somewhere along the way.

Comment: i think it might be a memory issue. once i start selecting more than around 15 fields, it gives that erro msg

Answer (score 1):

Cannot answer why but you could try like this;

```
--link server and login
EXEC master.sys.sp_addlinkedserver N'KSLAP208',N'SQL Server';
EXEC master.sys.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname='KSLAP208', 
                  @useself='false',
                  @rmtuser='username',
                  @rmtpassword='password';

        --DO YOUR JOB HERE 
        SELECT  TOP (10) * FROM  [KSLAP208].dbName.dbo.[tableName]

--drop server link and login
EXEC sp_droplinkedsrvlogin 'KSLAP208', NULL
EXEC sp_dropserver 'KSLAP208', NULL;
```

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried that but here is a [similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/afcb16e8-c0d3-4f9f-8ea7-b8ee06bb779f) and answer to it.

Comment: thank you again. the thing is my connection seems to be working i just cant select, but i will follow the lllink!

Comment: Also some details about `Windows authentication` mode in the [Remarks Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx)

Comment: so it looks like select individual fields works but i cannot select *

Comment: I checked `select * ...` works for me using this method. but I'm *not* on windows authentication mode.

Comment: i think it might be a memory issue. once i start selecting more than around 15 fields, it gives that erro msg