# Linked server working with three dot notation, but not with 4 part name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

Linked server working with three dot notation, but not with 4 part name in SQL Server.

For example: when I run

```
SELECT top 1 * 
FROM [POSTGREFGH]...DEPARTMENT
```

I am getting results, but when I try this:

```
SELECT top 1 * 
FROM [POSTGREFGH].MyDB.[MyShema].DEPARTMENT
```

I get this error:

> Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for
>   linked server "POSTGREFGH". A four-part name was supplied, but the
>   provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or
>   schema.

My source server is : `POSTGRESQL`

Where and what was wrong with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if the text in the post is the error message i think it is self explanatory: A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema -> change provider. if it is not so, please provide some useful information like the involved server software (all sql server?) the driver version and so on.

Comment: Is the `POSTGREFGH` server a PostgreSQL server, by any chance?

Comment: @Matt Gibson, Yes it is `PostgreSQL`

Comment: And you are 100% sure you use correct db/schema?

Comment: @lad2025, Yes I am 100% sure, not here but in my actual query. thanks

Comment: See the answer to this question:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779212/catastrophic-failure-trying-to-select-from-linked-server

Comment: We'll need to know what driver you're using and how you're setting things up. MSDASQL is the ODBC driver for OLEDB, so there's already a few layers here -- can you set the schema, etc. in the ODBC configuration instead of specifying it in the SELECT? With ODBC, you may need a different connection per schema, perhaps... You might need to change to a non-ODBC driver to get the functionality you need, but I don't know much about PostgreSQL drivers.